# wpf loader image animation with TransformGroup and Story Board

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a loader image in wpf using DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames and StoryBoard but i get this error 
Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(0).(1)[0].(RotateTransform)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

this is my code

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="LoaderAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform)" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="canvas" 
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="360"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource LoaderAnimation}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Viewbox  x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Height="323" Width="308"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup></TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=ProgressRing}" 
             Height="71" Canvas.Left="121" Canvas.Top="21" Width="69" Opacity="0.3"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Height="71" Width="69" Canvas.Left="194" Canvas.Top="52" Opacity="0.4"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Width="69" Height="71" Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="123" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Width="69" Height="71" Canvas.Left="190" Canvas.Top="198" Opacity="0.6"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Height="71" Canvas.Left="121" Canvas.Top="226" Width="69" Opacity="0.7"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Width="69" Height="71" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="194" Opacity="0.8"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Height="71" Width="69" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="123" Opacity="0.9"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" 
             Height="71" Width="69" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="52" Opacity="1.0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to animate the `Angle` property of the RotateTransform, the target property path should be this:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty=
    "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

or shorter:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].Angle"
```

You would however also have to add an actual RotateTransform instance to the TransformGroup:

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform />
    </TransformGroup>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

---

In case you don't have any other transforms in the group, you may as well write this:

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform />
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

and change the target property path to:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
```

Comment: adding   <RotateTransform /> inside  <TransformGroup> removed the error thank you @Clemens